# GeoIpLocation - How to get State and County? (OR, how to get State and County from a zip code) C#

Tags: c#, geolocation, location, geoip

I'm using a method to get an IipLocation object from an IP address. This is the code that returns the Location object:

```
public IIpLocation GetIpLocation(IPAddress ipAddress)
{
    ipAddress.CheckNull("ipAddress");

    IIpLocation ipLocation = null;
    try
    {
        //Try to look up the location using MaxMind.
        Location location = GetMaxMindIpLocation(ipAddress);

        //If the postal code is not present, then try to look it up with GeoNames.
        if (location != null && (location.PostalCode == null || location.PostalCode.Equals("")))
        {
            location.PostalCode = GetPostalCodeFromGeoNames(location);
        }

        if (location != null)
        {
            ipLocation = new GeoIpLocation(location);
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat(Resources.log_maxMindLookupFailed, ipAddress);
    }

    return ipLocation;
}
```

The IipLocation object has the following properties: `Region`, `RegionName`, `CountryCode`, `City`, `Postal Code`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`. However, I need the State and County. How can I get the state and county from the information that I have?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Where is `GetMaxMindIpLocation()` coming from? [MaxMind's official API](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet#city-database) has all of the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Census Block Conversions API](https://www.fcc.gov/general/census-block-conversions-api) accomplish this.

ex:

> http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json&latitude=28.35975&longitude=-81.421988&showall=true

Comment: This is great! Thanks